# WebForms Application_Error() to Azure Blob Storage - Site Hangs

Tags: .net, azure, webforms, azure-blob-storage

I've reproduced an issue in a sample repo where an unhandled exception in a WebForms project is getting caught in the Application_Error method in Global.asax.  I need that error log to write to Azure Blob Storage.  The Blob Storage code is working for handled errors within the application as well as when pulled into a console app. However, an unhandled exception will hang indefinitely (not fail) on the "**containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync()**" method (which is the first http call in the chain).

I believe the Blob Storage SDK does return an http 409 [Conflict] when checking if the container exists.  But when I comment that line out (and the container exists), it shows the same behavior when trying to upload the file.

Any ideas why this hangs?

Reproducible in [this repo](https://github.com/grayjeremy/WebFormsBlobStorage), just create your own storage account, add yourself as a blob contributor in IAM, update the Web.Config with the account and container name.

Some code snippets

```
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e) // Default.aspx
    {
        throw new Exception("is this the exception you are looking for?");
    }


    protected void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) //Global.asax
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

        Logger.AddLog(ex, string.Empty);
        if (ex.InnerException != null) Logger.AddLog(ex.InnerException, string.Empty);
        this.Response.Redirect("Error.aspx", true);
    }

    internal static void AddLog(Exception ex, string empty) // static class in Logger.cs
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ex.Message);
        string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt";
        string storageAccountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storageAccountName"].ToString();
        string storageContainerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storageContainerName"].ToString();

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {

            StreamToCloudStorageAsync(storageAccountName, storageContainerName, stream, fileName).GetAwaiter().GetResult();

        }
    }

    async static Task StreamToCloudStorageAsync(string accountName, string containerName, Stream sourceStream, string destinationFileName) // static class in Logger.cs
    {
        // Construct the blob container endpoint from the arguments.
        string containerEndpoint = string.Format("https://{0}.blob.core.windows.net/{1}",
                                                accountName,
                                                containerName);

        // Get a credential and create a client object for the blob container.
        BlobContainerClient containerClient = new BlobContainerClient(new Uri(containerEndpoint), new DefaultAzureCredential());

        // Create the container if it does not exist.
        await containerClient.CreateIfNotExistsAsync();

        var blobClient = containerClient.GetBlobClient(destinationFileName);

        // Upload text to a new block blob.
        var blob = await blobClient.UploadAsync(sourceStream);
    }
```

Any ideas why this hangs?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`.GetAwaiter().GetResult();` is a blocking your code and is leading to deadlocks in your code. See also [this blog post](https://blog.stephencleary.com/2012/07/dont-block-on-async-code.html).

You should make `AddLog` return a Task and `await` the call to `StreamToCloudStorageAsync`:

```cs
internal static Task AddLogAsync(Exception ex, string empty) // static class in Logger.cs
    {
        byte[] byteArray = Encoding.ASCII.GetBytes(ex.Message);
        string fileName = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() + ".txt";
        string storageAccountName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storageAccountName"].ToString();
        string storageContainerName = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storageContainerName"].ToString();

        using (MemoryStream stream = new MemoryStream(byteArray))
        {

            await StreamToCloudStorageAsync(storageAccountName, storageContainerName, stream, fileName);

        }
    }
```

Then refactor the `Application_Error` event handler to proper await the async call:

```cs
    protected async void Application_Error(object sender, EventArgs e) //Global.asax
    {
        Exception ex = Server.GetLastError();

        await Logger.AddLogAsync(ex, string.Empty);
        if (ex.InnerException != null) 
            await Logger.AddLogAsync(ex.InnerException, string.Empty);
        this.Response.Redirect("Error.aspx", true);
    }
```

Normally one should avoid using `async void` but event handler are an exception.

**Bonus**

Your code only logs the exception and first inner exception if available.

```cs
        await Logger.AddLogAsync(ex, string.Empty);
        if (ex.InnerException != null) 
            await Logger.AddLogAsync(ex.InnerException, string.Empty);
```

If you want to log all inner exceptions try

```cs
while(ex != null)
{
    await Logger.AddLogAsync(ex, string.Empty);
    ex = ex.InnerException
}
```